# WPF: How to pass an instance of System.Type as the Binding.ConverterParameter via XAML?

Tags: wpf, binding, parameters, converters

I have some CLR type "MyType". Is it possible to pass the typeof(MyType) result as the Binding.ConverterParameter via XAML?

```
{Binding Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, **ConverterParameter=???**}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [`{x:Type MyType}` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx).

Note that you'll need to import an XML namespace for the type.

Comment: It is worth noticing that this markup extension can also be used as a XAML object: `<x:Type TypeName="prefix:typeNameValue"/>`